# Around third of Events have null session Ids in Big Query GA4 Events Table

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

We have connected GA4 to Google Big Query. Events table in Big Query has null session Ids for 30% of events which doesn't sound right. This is causing a big discrepancy in session count between Google Analytics 4 dashboard and Big Query data.

> select   event_date,   count(*) as EventsWithNullSessionIds from
> `xxxxxxxx.analytics_358337460.events_2024012*` where (select value.int_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'ga_session_id')
> is null group by event_date order by event_date desc

Comment: are you using measurement protocol?